# differential equation with offset, characteristic polynomial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen a lot of example problems on differential equations on forming a characteristic polynomial equation with the following diff-eq form:

$\ddot{y}^2 + y = 0$

But what do you do when there is a term that is just a constant (an offset) in your differential equation:

$-\ddot{y} + 1 = 0  $

I know that is a simple trivial example that could probably be solved directly, but imagine it's a more difficult equation with an offset. And I am specifically asking about the characteristic polynomial equation method of solving this diff-eq, not using the Laplace/Inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Is the 1st term of the DE square of the 2nd derivative or just second derivative?

Comment: just the second derivative

Comment: The method with characteristic equation works only for linear ODE's. But the first given equation isn't linear. The second equation can be easily integrated.